# "Summarize" JSON data with php

Tags: php, json

Say I got the following JSON:

```
{
users: [
{
  qnt: "3",
  post: "j8v2g5",
  contact: "foo@bar.com",
  id: "1"
 },
 {
  qnt: "10",
  post: "xxxyyy",
  contact: "foo@foo.net",
  id: "6"
 },
 {
  qnt: "3",
  post: "xxxyyy",
  contact: "bar@foo.org",
  id: "4"
 }
]
}
```

I want all children of `users` with the same `post` to have their `qnt` added together and remove `contact` and `id` from the final result.

I want the result to look like this:

```
{
users: [
 {
  qnt: "3",
  post: "j8v2g5"
 },
 {
  qnt: "13",
  post: "xxxyyy"
 }
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you are stuck somewhere we'll be happy to help, but you can't expect us to do all the work for you! Unless I can send you an invoice that is ;-)

Comment: Convert it to array by json_decode() and then something like array_walk to build up an array. If post is in_array, then add qnt to the qnt. Then encode the result via json_encode().

Comment: @Pevara Thank you for your help, I don't know how I would do it without you :) Seriously now, if you can't and don't even consider helping - don't bother commenting.

Comment: Excuse me? I was just trying to tell you in a friendly way that you should at least show some effort. SO is for solving concrete programming problems, not a free 'write my code' service! Perhaps you should read the terms first http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Pevara I don't know how to do this, okay? For a very long time I avoided doing this because I didn't know how to do this but now, doing a workaround would make it extremely hard to work with.

Comment: @ChristopherPecoraro I don't know how to build a function around that that will do this. I never did something like this before. That's why I'm hoping someone would be able to show how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probabely be recieveing `$myJson` from somewhere and then you can return `$rsultsJson`. I suggest putting this whole thing in a function or a class method.

```
$myJson = '{"users": [{  "qnt": "3",  "post": "j8v2g5",  "contact": "foo@bar.com",  "id": "1" }, {  "qnt": "10",  "post": "xxxyyy",  "contact": "foo@foo.net",  "id": "6" }, {  "qnt": "3",  "post": "xxxyyy",  "contact": "bar@foo.org",  "id": "4" }]}';
$usersObject=json_decode($myJson);
$usersArray = $usersObject->users;
$postCount = array();

foreach ($usersArray as $user) {
    if (array_key_exists($user->post, $postCount)) {
        $postCount[$user->post] += $user->qnt;
    } else {
        $postCount[$user->post] = $user->qnt;
    }   

}

$results = new stdClass();
$results->users = array();
foreach ($postCount as $post => $count) {
    $user = new stdClass();
    $user->qnt = $count;
    $user->post = $post;    
    $results->users[] = $user;
}

$rsultsJson = json_encode($results);
```